# Why “Many and many A year ago”, not “Many, many years ago? Are they same?

Tags: idioms, numbers, many-a

I was amused with the introductory part of the [New York Times’ article（September 13)](http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/09/13/as-comics-say-these-kids-today-i-tell-ya/?hp) by Dick Cavett called “As comics say, ‘These kids today! I tell ya!’” that begins:

> **“Many and many a year ago**, in the kingdom of ABC, Woody Allen was one
>   of my very first guests. And we consented to take questions from an
>   eager audience of mostly young people. Like ourselves. The questioner
>   looked like a high school girl and shouted to Woody from the balcony,
>
> “Do you think sex is dirty?”
>
> Allen: “It is if you do it right.”

Besides Allen’s exquisite riposte, I was drawn to the beginning words, “Many and many a year ago”.

Is it the same as “many many years ago”? Why is ‘year’ in a singular form when you are referring to multiple years' time span?

Is “many and many a” an idiom, or a set pattern of phrase?  Can I say 'I bought many and many a book this month" instead of 'I bought many books this month,' and 'I have many and many a question to post in EL&U' instead of 'I have a lot of questions ---'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What RyeBread said.

"It was many and many a year ago, in a kingdom by the sea" is the opening of a great poem by Edgar Allen Poe.  [Anabel Lee](http://www.bartleby.com/101/695.html)

Presumably  Dick Cavett assumes that anyone over a certain age educated in the US (i.e. those who were viewers of his TV show) read the poem in school, and will understand the reference.

Comment: I can wrap my head around this phrase only in the equation, ‘many + many × a year = many many years.’

Comment: You are right: the surface meaning is "many years ago".  And "in the kingdom of ABC" means "at ABC".  But in addition to this, there is the reference to Poe.

Answer (score 3):

He stole the phrase from Poe.  Just using a famous quote as an attention getter.  I personally think people should have their own style but some people like it.